# Fail to git rm files to folder with wildcard

Tags: git, powershell

Here I have few `.html` files in my repo. I want move them into a new folder `src`. I can't mv them one by one cause there are too much files,
 so I tried `git mv *.html src`.
However it responses `fatal: bad source, source=*.html, destination=src/*.html`.
What can I do to solve that?
ps : using powershell

Comment: Are you sure you run the `git` command in the correct directory? I just ran it in a directory that doesn't contain `.html` files and I received the same error message.

Comment: Does the `src` folder exist prior to executing `git mv *.html src'?

Comment: Yes, the I am in the correct dir with `.html` files, and the `src` folder has been created before.